# Easy way to square `*args`

Tags: python, list, arguments

The code below prints the square root of 7+6+3 (=4).

```
import math

def notdist(*args):
    return math.sqrt(sum(args))
    
print(notdist(7,6,3))
```

I want somenting like this:

```
import math

def dist(*args):
    return math.sqrt(sum(args**2))
    
print(dist(7,6,3))
```

for calculating the distance from O(0,0), but this is giving the error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'

I know that I can use another code like:

```
import math

def uglydist(*args):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(args)):
        s = s + args[i]**2
    return math.sqrt(s)

print(uglydist(3,4)) # = 5
```

but I 'm wondering if it is an easy way to modify the first code. Something like the second code, but correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use `numpy` arrays as they provide this feature. for a `array1 = numpy.array(args)`, `array1 = array1**2` should work

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra , thanks for your answer! I just start python, so I can't use properly `numpy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps with a generator expression inside `sum`:

```
def dist(*args):
    return math.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in args))
```

Answer (score 1):

using the `for` like this would be better, but I think this too isn't what you wanted

```py
import math

def NotSoGoodDist(*args):
    s = 0
    for i in args:
        s = s + i**2
    return math.sqrt(s)

print(NotSoGoodDist(3,4)) # = 5
```